# How to convert Java Array or List to Scala String*

Tags: java, apache-spark

Here I have a spark java project, but when I use dataset API such as selectExpr(String*) method to process my data, I need to convert the parameters in the form of Java Array or List to Scala String*, if I use Java Array as parameters in the method selectExpr(String*), the method would treat the Java Array as a String which cause failure.
for example, in my code:

```
String[] selectFields = new String[]{"provinceCode","cpCode","psId"}
datasets.selectExpr(selectFields).........
```

After I submit my Job, the error occurs:

```
mismatched input ',' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 12)

== SQL ==
provinceCode,contentTypeCode,psId
```

I really need your help, thank you

Comment: the dataset schema is composed of fields such as "provinceCode","cpCode","psId", mkString(",") method will cause "provinceCode,cpCode,psId" which is not exist in the schema

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a Hello world in my local using `spark-sql_2.13-3.4.0` with `JDK 11` and I was able to call the method `dataframe.selectExpr(javaArray)` like you are doing in the example provided.

My `pom.xml`

```
  <artifactId>hello-world-java-spark</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

I have a json file with the following content

```
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}
```

My hello world class

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class HelloWorldJavaSpark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("Customer Aggregation pipeline")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> dataFrame = sparkSession.read().json("src/main/resources/people.json");

        dataFrame.printSchema();

        String[] columns = {"name", "age"}; // java array
        dataFrame
            .selectExpr(columns) // java array being used as param
            .foreach((ForeachFunction) x -> System.out.println(x));

    }

}
```

I was able to execute it as a java app from IntelliJ and also using `spark-submit`

mvn command to package

```
mvn package
```

Once the jar is generated I executed spark-submit like this

```
spark-submit --class "HelloWorldJavaSpark" target/hello-world-java-spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And this was the output

```
[Michael,null]
[Andy,30]
[Justin,19]
```

If your context is not similar (spark version, jdk, maybe operative system, etc), please provide more details